# gdb: how to learn which shared library loaded a shared library in question

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, shared-libraries

I need to get the list of shared libraries used by an app in runtime. Most of them can be listed by `ldd`, but some can be seen only with `gdb -p <pid>` and by running the gdb command `info sharedlib`.

It would really help, if I could learn in some way: for a chosen library (in the list, output by `info sharedlib`), which library (of the same list) had caused to load it. Is there any way to learn it in gdb or in some other way? Because sometimes, I see a loaded library in the list and cannot get why it is there and which (probably, previously loaded in memory) library loaded it.

**UPDATE:**

I attach a screen shot of gdb showing the info that I need. I used breakpoint on `dlopen`, as it was suggested in comments and in the answer. The command `x/s $rdi` prints out the first argument of `dlopen`, as by Linux System V ABI, i.e. it prints the name if the library, about which I want to learn who loaded it (`libdebuginfod.so.1`). I put it here just for those who are curious. In my case, it can be seen, that the `libdebuginfod.so.1` was loaded by `libdw.so.1` (as shown by `bt` command).

[image]

Comment: If `ldd` doesn't show it, maybe it was loaded via [`dlopen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)?

Comment: Afaik, it is. This is why I have to use gdb -p with "info dll" cmd.

Comment: Then, set a breakpoint on `dlopen`?

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea! I think it's a very good one. I will try, and write an update.

Comment: I have just tried you method. I set breakpoint on dlopen, even though it was complaining with "Function "dlopen" not defined. Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y". Then I launched "x/s $rdi" and saw my lib in question"libdebuginfod.so.1". Then I used "bt" and saw that it was called by /lib64/libdw.so.1 . I update my question with a screen shot for those who will be interested. Btw, if you write your answer briefly, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to learn it in gdb or in some other way?

There are a few ways.

You can run the program with `env LD_DEBUG=files /path/to/exe`.

This will produce output similar to:

```
 LD_DEBUG=files /bin/date
     76042:
     76042:     file=libc.so.6 [0];  needed by /bin/date [0]
```

It is the *needed by* part that you most care about.

You could also use GDB and use `set set stop-on-solib-events 1`. This will produce output similar to:

```
Stopped due to shared library event:
  Inferior loaded /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

At that point, you could execute `where` command and observe which `dlopen()` call caused the new library to be loaded.

You could also set a breakpoint on `dlopen()` and do the same.

The `stop-on-solib-events` may be better if your executable repeatedly `dlopen()`s the same library -- the library set will not change when you `dlopen()` the same library again, and you'll stop when you don't care to stop. Setting `stop-on-solib-events` avoids such unnecessary stops.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It contains a great amount of very useful info that I hope I will use many times.